# Name Search in Python

Tags: python

In this program the user is supposed to enter a boy's name and a girl's name. The program is then supposed to output whether the two names were in the files or not. My program runs as of now, but no matter what name I enter it outputs that the name was not on the list. What do I need to do to fix this problem?

```
foundGirl = False
findGirl = input("What is the girl's name?: ")
girlNames = open('GirlNames.txt', 'r')
searchGirls = girlNames.readline()

if searchGirls == findGirl:
    print(findGirl, 'is found in the top 200 baby names.')
    print()

    foundGirl = True

searchGirls = girlNames.readline()

if not foundGirl:
    print('That girl name was not on the list.')

foundBoy = False
findBoy = input("What is the boy's name?: ")
boyNames = open('BoyNames.txt', 'r')
searchBoys = boyNames.readline()

if searchBoys == findBoy:
    print(findBoy, 'is found in the top 200 baby names.')
    print()

    foundBoy = True

searchBoys = boyNames.readlines()

if not foundBoy:
    print('That boy name was not on the list.')

girlNames.close()
boyNames.close()
```

Comment: how is girlsnames.txt formatted?

Comment: `.readline()` will have a `\n` (newline) at the end, so it would never match the input (assuming you're entering just the name on command line). I'm not sure how you're reading 200 names in one `readline()` though, or how `==` is supposed to check if its contained in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your names are listed in the file and separated by a carriage return, you will either have to create a loop with `readline()` to iterate through all the lines or put all the lines in an array with `readlines()`.

I would recommend the second solution:

```
girlNames = open('GirlNames.txt', 'r')
searchGirls = girlNames.readlines()
```

`readlines` will keep the trailing `\n` for all the lines in the text file, so you will want to get rid of that for all the names that you've just added to your array:

```
searchGirls = [s.strip() for s in searchGirls]
```

Then simply check if your string is contained in the array:

```
if findGirl in searchGirls:
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each text file is structured where each name is on a single line, I see two potential problems that could be occurring by themselves, or both occurring together:

1. The first is that since `file.readline` returns a `\n` (newline) character at the end of every line, it won't match your user input exactly.
2. The second problem I see is that you're simply not reading enough lines. Your could seems to only read two names at most. What if the target name is on the third line, or fourth line? You need to loop over *each line*, testing if it matches the user input.

Here is how I would re-write your code:

```
girl_name = input() # prompt left out for brevity
boy_name = input() # prompt left out for brevity

with open('BoyNames.txt', 'r') as boy_names, open('GirlNames.txt', 'r') as girl_names:
    if any(name.strip() == boy_name for name in boy_names):
        print(boy_name, 'was found in the top 200 boy names.')
    if any(name.strip() == girl_name for name in girl_names):
        print(girl_name, 'was found in the top 200 girl names.')
```